# How do you assign nodes a property using G.Nodes?

Tags: matlab

I have a graph with nodes assigned a number. I want this to be the node's "status" so that if I have a node X and I write G.Nodes.Status(X), then Matlab will tell me whether its number is 0 and 1. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just write:

```
G.Nodes.Status = X
```

Where `X` is a vector of the status of the nodes. `X` should have a value for each node in the same order that they appear in `G.Nodes`.

```
G = graph([1 1], [2 3]);
X = [1;0;1];
G.Nodes.Status = X;
G.Nodes.Status(2)

ans =
     0
```

Comment: What if your vector X is a vertical vector, i.e. a matrix with only one column (not sure if that's a proper vector or not, but hopefully you understand what I mean)

Comment: The vector in the example _is_ a one column vector, see my edit for a clarification.

Comment: @HollyPorter Please let me know if this answers your question. and consider accepting it (by the green V on the left) if it is.